# Subdomain alias in nginx and nodejs/express

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, static, subdomain

I am trying to add a subdomain of my site. I have http://www.myweb.com/app/ and I just want http://app.myweb.com/ witch is the same of /app.
The content of /app is served by express in nodejs.

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name .myweb.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/myweb.log;

    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;                             
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
    }

}
```

And in nodejs I have:

```
http.use('/app', express.static(__dirname + '/static/app'));
```

But not sure if the statics should be served by nginx or nodejs/express

Answer (score 0):

Searching in the web how use subdomain.

```
upstream your_app_name {
    server localhost:3000;
    keepalive 8;
}

server {
    listen 80;    
    server_name ~^(?<sub>.+)\.domain\.com$;    

    location ~* \.html {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

      proxy_pass http://your_app_name/$sub;
      proxy_redirect off;
    } 
 }
```

Sorry; my english its very bad